# Is it possible to run javascript with an image only

Tags: javascript, image, jpeg

For example,

I have an image: `www.domain.com/image.jpg`

If someone where to go to this image, can I run javascript on this image. The extension of the file to something like `.html`. The file extension should be `.jpg` (so `www.domain.com/image.jpg`).

An example of the process:

1. Bob goes to `www.domain.com/image.jpg`
2. A javascript where of `alert("Hello! Thanks for looking at my image");` runs.
3. Bob sees a pop up which says `Hello! Thanks for looking at my image`

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb

Comment: Sounds like you're interested in a `stegosploit`? Something like: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/can-simply-decompressing-a-jpeg-image-trigger-an-exploit or https://www.opswat.com/blog/hacking-pictures-stegosploit-and-how-stop-it

Comment: @BlitzNinja29 No. Because the user would have to visit a `.html` link. I am saying the user visits a `.jpg` link (which is an image only).

Comment: You can have the URL end in `.jpg` or whatever extension you like, but you can only run Javascript on *an actual page / document* - an image alone (eg. a served JPG) can't have Javascript run on it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So is it possible to run a javascript where the url ends in `.jpg` or `.png` or `.gif`

Comment: @Micheal No. If it is, your browser is _very_ broken.

Comment: Yes (I think), it would just be a bit odd to serve an HTML page on an address whose file extension implies that the page is actually just an image

Comment: @CertainPerformance How so? As user124 said the it would mean your browser is very broken.

Comment: What the URL happens to end in doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the content that's actually being served by the server when that URL is requested, I'm pretty sure - though, it *usually* does, which is why I said it's a pretty odd thing to do.

Comment: If your URL ending with `.jpg` is an actual `image/jpeg` binary image file, then no, you can't run JS - however, it's possible to set up a web server so that when it receives a request for a `file.jpeg` it actually serves a `text/html` file that has an `<img src="file.jpeg">` and some javascript.

Comment: @Jack I don't think OP is looking so far as stegosploit. More likely similar to many image hosting sites (especially for special kind of images :) ) where link looks like image link but really full pages with adds and whatsnot.

Answer (score 1):

Can link with path portion ending in ".jpg" run JavaScript in browser? - Yes and no... depending on whether browser expects a page (direct navigation or clicking on a link) or rendering an image (img tag, background image,...).

If modern browser expects an image (i.e. `<img src="cats.jpg">` or any other place where image is needed like in CSS backgrounds) it will reject any responses that are not coming back as [content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) "image/..." (or similar) and will try to interpret response as an image if content type look like an image. In <s>no</s>most cases browser will not render such response as HTML with JavaScript  running (according to [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604492/is-it-possible-to-run-javascript-with-an-image-only/53604720?noredirect=1#comment94072263_53604720) SVG responses may contain JavaScript) .

If browser just navigates to a page it does not expect any particular type of response . Server tells what response is by providing content type header. If the is no header browser may try to guess type of response by looking at first bytes. In any case if response comes as HTML the browser will simply render it as a page irrespective of how url looked like. I.e.  http://www.example.com/cats.jpg  may as well return CSS or HTML depending on how server is configured.

Comment: I clicked on that link expecting to get 15 viruses and was very disappointed

Comment: @user124 as you know example.com is [reserved domain name](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved) and will not serve any "interesting" content (also in this case it happily demonstrates rendering of HTML in response to "image like" url).

Comment: I know - I was just joking ;)

Comment: nit-picks: "In no cases browser will render such response as HTML with JavaScript running." in iframe, object or embed *image/svg+xml* will execute js. In img and aforementioned *image/svg+xml* will render HTML. And are you sure browsers will check magic numbers? From experience they only trust what they've been given as Content-Type.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, edit in link to your comment. Yes, I'm quite sure that at least IE would do mime sniffing for page request (when it does not know what to expect) as "content-type" is not required header. For cases when browser knows what to expect (CSS/JS/image) modern browsers will generally reject mismatched responses.